# IP address from getifaddrs and ipconfig don't match

Tags: networking

On my mac, I did a command line

```
ipconfig getifaddr en1
```

and it shows

```
10.0.0.2
```

However when I use the

```
struct ifaddrs *id;
int success=0;
success=getifaddrs(&id);
printf("Network Address of %s :- %d\n",id->ifa_name,id->ifa_addr);
```

it shows

```
Network Address of lo0 :- 8393376
```

So, how does the `10.0.0.2` relate to `8393376`?

Seems like they don't match from the two ways of finding the IP address.

Comment: `ifa_addr` is a pointer...

Answer (score 1):

```
 id->ifa_addr
```

Is some kind of `struct sockaddr` (e.g. a `struct sockaddr_in`), which contains the type of 
the address (e.g. IPv4, IPv6, Ethernet MAC address, or similar), and the
binary representation of the address. It is not a string that you can print with printf's %s.

You might be able to use this:

```
void
print_sockaddr(struct sockaddr* addr,const char *name)
{
    char addrbuf[128] ;

    addrbuf[0] = 0;
    if(addr->sa_family == AF_UNSPEC)
        return;

    switch(addr->sa_family) {
    case AF_INET:
        inet_ntop(addr->sa_family,&((struct sockaddr_in*)addr)->sin_addr,
                  addrbuf,sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
        break;
    case AF_INET6:
        inet_ntop(addr->sa_family, &((struct sockaddr_in6*)addr)->sin6_addr,
                  addrbuf,sizeof(struct sockaddr_in6));
        break;
    default:
        sprintf(addrbuf,"Unknown family (%d)",(int)addr->sa_family);
        break;

    }
    printf("%-16s %s\n",name,addrbuf);
}

...

print_sockaddr(id->ifa_addr,id->ifa_name);
```

getifaddrs returns a linked list of `struct ifaddrs` , representing each interface.

You'll need to do:

```
struct ifaddrs *addrs,*tmp;

if(getifaddrs(&addrs) != 0) {
    perror("getifaddrs");
    return 1;
}
for(tmp = addrs; tmp ; tmp = tmp->ifa_next) {
    print_sockaddr(tmp->ifa_addr, tmp->ifa_name);
}
freeifaddrs(addrs);
```

Answer (score 0):

Dude, to print the IP you need do this:

```
struct sockaddr_in * ip;
ip = (struct sockaddr_in *) id->ifa_addr;

if (ip->sin_family == AF_INET)
    printf("Network Address: %s\n",inet_ntoa(ip->sin_addr));
```

try do this.